# How to fix login loop after GPU switch

Tags: nvidia, login, amd-graphics, gpu

I've been using an NVidia GTS 450 for years and I just switched to an AMD RX 480. I opened my desktop, switched the hardware and booted. Now I'm facing a login loop with .xsession-errors containing

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Purge any Nvidia drivers left. Use `nomodeset` as a boot parameter if needed.

Comment: Well, you just saved my life. Whish I could give you points but I can't do anything in a comment. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it. If not in a few hours, I'll do it my self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purge any Nvidia drivers left:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Reboot.

Use the `nomodeset` boot parameter if needed. It shouldn't be because the system should now run with open-source driver for AMD.